# Importing OpenTelemetry trace data from Spring Boot application to Elastic APM - views are missing data

Tags: java, spring-boot, elasticsearch, open-telemetry, apm

I have a Spring Boot application with Spring Cloud Sleuth, OpenTelemetry instrumentation and OpenTelemetry exporter OTLP.

This is a gist of dependencies:

- `spring-cloud-starter-sleuth` without Brave, because we are using OpenTelemetry instrumentation
- `spring-cloud-sleuth-otel-autoconfigure` which introduces OpenTelemetry instrumentation libs and provides Spring autoconfiguration
- `opentelemetry-exporter-otlp` for sending data to apm server

  ```
     <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-sleuth</artifactId>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-sleuth-brave</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-sleuth-otel-autoconfigure</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.opentelemetry</groupId>
        <artifactId>opentelemetry-exporter-otlp</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.grpc/grpc-netty -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.grpc</groupId>
        <artifactId>grpc-netty-shaded</artifactId>
        <version>1.43.0</version>
    </dependency>
  ```

I have only basic configuration in my `application.yml`:

```
spring:
  sleuth:
    enabled: true
    otel:
      config:
        trace-id-ratio-based: 1.0
      exporter:
        otlp:
          endpoint: http://localhost:8200
```

With this setup I successfully see some data in APM. Example screens:

[image: Traces]

[image: Trace sample]

However if I look into Elastic documentation, I see that their screens have additional data present: [Traces](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/apm/get-started/current/distributed-tracing.html#_visualize_distributed_tracing).

To me, it looks like span and transaction names are missing (I only see HTTP GET instead of a name), at least they are present in the documentation images.

Anyone has an idea why is this happening and how to fix this?

This is example trace document in Elastic:

```js
const EXAMPLE = {
  "_index": "apm-7.15.2-metric-000001",
  "_type": "_doc",
  "_id": "AYVKCH8BxjGANUnHPDgq",
  "_version": 1,
  "_score": 1,
  "_source": {
    "_doc_count": 2,
    "agent": {
      "name": "opentelemetry/java"
    },
    "processor": {
      "name": "metric",
      "event": "metric"
    },
    "transaction.duration.histogram": {
      "counts": [
        1,
        1
      ],
      "values": [
        1439,
        10495
      ]
    },
    "metricset.name": "transaction",
    "observer": {
      "hostname": "0798ff612508",
      "id": "6a12bcef-5e7e-45b3-aee6-f2af4e175c3f",
      "ephemeral_id": "389ee9b1-d4c4-4d67-b46a-bfcaa77b7b79",
      "type": "apm-server",
      "version": "7.15.2",
      "version_major": 7
    },
    "@timestamp": "2022-02-17T15:25:56.160Z",
    "timeseries": {
      "instance": "summary-service:HTTP GET:11ed2dc65a946e45"
    },
    "ecs": {
      "version": "1.11.0"
    },
    "service": {
      "name": "summary-service"
    },
    "event": {
      "ingested": "2022-02-17T15:25:57.161730700Z",
      "outcome": "success"
    },
    "transaction": {
      "result": "HTTP 2xx",
      "root": true,
      "name": "HTTP GET",
      "type": "request"
    }
  },
  "fields": {
    "transaction.name.text": [
      "HTTP GET"
    ],
    "_doc_count": [
      2
    ],
    "service.name": [
      "summary-service"
    ],
    "processor.name": [
      "metric"
    ],
    "observer.version_major": [
      7
    ],
    "observer.hostname": [
      "0798ff612508"
    ],
    "transaction.result": [
      "HTTP 2xx"
    ],
    "transaction.duration.histogram": [
      {
        "counts": [
          1,
          1
        ],
        "values": [
          1439,
          10495
        ]
      }
    ],
    "transaction.type": [
      "request"
    ],
    "metricset.name": [
      "transaction"
    ],
    "observer.id": [
      "6a12bcef-5e7e-45b3-aee6-f2af4e175c3f"
    ],
    "event.ingested": [
      "2022-02-17T15:25:57.161Z"
    ],
    "@timestamp": [
      "2022-02-17T15:25:56.160Z"
    ],
    "observer.ephemeral_id": [
      "389ee9b1-d4c4-4d67-b46a-bfcaa77b7b79"
    ],
    "timeseries.instance": [
      "summary-service:HTTP GET:11ed2dc65a946e45"
    ],
    "observer.version": [
      "7.15.2"
    ],
    "ecs.version": [
      "1.11.0"
    ],
    "observer.type": [
      "apm-server"
    ],
    "transaction.root": [
      true
    ],
    "processor.event": [
      "metric"
    ],
    "transaction.name": [
      "HTTP GET"
    ],
    "agent.name": [
      "opentelemetry/java"
    ],
    "event.outcome": [
      "success"
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: What I also tried is import data into Azure Insights in 2 ways: 1) similar setup  as here, and I see pretty much same results as in Elastic APM. 2) Removed all tracing dependencies (sleuth, OTEL, OTEL exporter) and added their tracing agent (OpenTelemetry based) which produced expected results - I actually saw more useful presentation of data.

Comment: Hi Uros K, I did similar in my app but my service is not getting visible in Jaeger console. Which port we should use in exporter.otlp.endpoint? I have installed jaeger all in one via docker. https://www.jaegertracing.io/docs/1.33/getting-started/#all-in-one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> To me, it looks like span and transaction names are missing (I only see HTTP GET instead of a name)

No, they are not missing. The reason you are seeing name as `HTTP GET` is due to preference for less cardinal names and the semantic conventions for tracing data. There is a detailed explanation about the naming conventions for the HTTP spans here https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-specification/blob/main/specification/trace/semantic_conventions/http.md#name. Any data generated by auto-instrumentation libraries will adhere to the semantic conventions specification. I am guessing the visualisation from the linked vendor is coming from manual instrumentation where you as an end user can give any name (although it is recommended everyone uses less cardinal values but there is not enforcement there). I don't think there is anything you can "fix" here.

Comment: If you look at their documentation here: https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-specification/blob/main/specification/trace/api.md#span there is an example table, stating that span name GET is too general and that good names are: get_account, get_account/{accountId} which in my opinion are also better. Why is this a problem can be seen from this screen: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ibxuN.png which is not providing enough information to know what those traces are.

Comment: Agree, that HTTP GET is not enough. I am not sure which lib is producing this tracing data. They can may be update the code to try to provide better name such as :accounts/{accountId}. You may want to try discussing this with the authors of code which sends the data.

Comment: I agree. Here are some more links on that topic: https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-dotnet/issues/1277 , https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-java-instrumentation/discussions/2606 , https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-java-instrumentation/blob/60ee981d07c92dc0b0ec32d1912c883f0b055c30/instrumentation-api/src/main/java/io/opentelemetry/instrumentation/api/tracer/HttpClientTracer.java#L218